# Postgresql createrole permission for user

Tags: postgresql, users, role

I created a role with `createrole` flag, but users in this role trying to create users fail with permissions denied. Do I need to assign the createrole to each user instead of just the role (group)?

my steps were as follow:

```
create role group1 with nologin createrole;
create user user1 PASSWORD 'password' in role group1;
```

then login as user1 and trying to `create user newuser` fails with the error `permission denied to create role`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html), you have to use `SET ROLE` before actually using the createrole privilege.

Connect as `user1` and issue

```
SET ROLE group1;
CREATE ROLE newuser;
```

Also, beware - `CREATEROLE` allows privilege escalation. This is also said in the docs.